# Exception "mutating method sent to immutable object"

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I Had an exception in the line `[array removeObjectsInArray:toRemove];` in the method below and can't understand what's wrong with it..

```
- (void) handleDearchForTerm:(NSString *)searchTerm
{
    NSMutableArray *sectionsToRemove = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self resetSearch];
    for (NSString *key in _keys)
    {
        NSMutableArray *array = [_names valueForKey:key];
        NSMutableArray *toRemove = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (NSString *name in array)
        {
            if ([name rangeOfString:searchTerm options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location == NSNotFound)
                [toRemove addObject:name];
        }
        if ([array count] == [toRemove count])
            [sectionsToRemove addObject:key];
        [array removeObjectsInArray:toRemove];
    }
    [_keys removeObjectsInArray:sectionsToRemove];
    [_table reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that [_names valueForKey:key] returns an NSMutableArray* and not a NSArray* ?

Comment: I don't see alloc/init for *array. And as the comment above sugests, try NSMutableArray *array = [[_names valueForKey:key] mutablecopy];

Comment: Well, it may make the error message go away, but if you were hoping to mutate the existing array in place, it won't do what you expect.

Answer (score 3):

Probably array is just instance of `NSArray`， but not `NSMutableArray`, you shall check `_names setObject:forKeys:`

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *names; .. this is the example from the book ..

Comment: yeah, how u construct names ? or check where u call method setObject:forKeys:

Comment: If `_names` is a dictionary of `NSArray`s `[_names valueForKey:key]` will return a `NSArray` not a `NSMutableArray`. Collections do not retain mutability of their contents.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
 NSMutableArray *array = [_names valueForKey:key];
```

To:

```
 NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[_names valueForKey:key]];
```

Or:

```
 NSMutableArray *array = [[_names valueForKey:key] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: `NSMutableArray *array = [[_names valueForKey:key] mutableCopy];`